# How to change app-box design when scrolling?

Tags: polymer-2.x

I am using polymer 2.0, the starter kit, to make a nice layout like this: [Sample](http://rudhisasmito.com/demo/walls/index.html).

I am just learning the new app-layout elements, for example app-box, but I don't know how to change the position, size and other properties when the user scrolls down and it is currently positioned at the top.

Now I just have this: [MyPage](https://restaurante-41108.firebaseapp.com/). Do you have an example or a recommendation about which element should I use to get a similar effect like this page: [Sample](http://rudhisasmito.com/demo/walls/index.html)?

Answer (score 1):

There are two demo applications from [polymer-project](http://polymer-project.org).

1. Shop

   Demo: [shop.polymer-project.org](http://shop.polymer-project.org)

   Source code: [Github](https://github.com/Polymer/shop)

   Read about how it's built in Case study: [the Shop app](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/toolbox/news-case-study)
2. News

   Demo: [news.polymer-project.org](http://news.polymer-project.org)

   Source code: [Github](https://github.com/Polymer/news)

   Read about how it's built in Case study: [the News app](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/toolbox/news-case-study)

For the similar effect in header(or toolbar or menu) like your [sample](http://rudhisasmito.com/demo/walls/index.html), check out the **News** app.

Thanks!

Comment: thanks, but News app is not in polymer 2.0, is it? Im lost with the changes and that example is using polymer 1.0 :(.

Comment: Can you start a fiddle and let me know where you got stuck?